# Requirement for exposing a COM Object

Tags: windows, powershell, com, registry

In powershell, when using new-object to instantiate, or get a reference to (or whatever you want to call it), a COM object I recall that the COM object needed to have a certain property to be able to expose it's functionality (through the registry I think is how it did it, via its Class-Id or something).

I can't for the life of me remember what the technical term for the "exposing" was, just that if the object/module/dll/assembly wasn't configured appropriately, the object wasn't available for instantiating with new-object (so that you couldn't just start instantiating objects within 3rd party software I assume is why an explicit setting must be made).

If anyone knows what this term is called it would be very helpful.  Its the first step I'm taking in reusing a clients software functionality from a webservice, so I don't have to rewrite all over.

Much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the COM server (binary) which creates a number of registry entries.  The primary one PowerShell needs is the ProgID.  Also, register a typelib should help PowerShell provide you with member information on the created object.  You typically use regsvr32 for a native COM binary and regasm for a managed COM binary.

Comment: the name regasm always makes me giggle. But for me, gutter humor is high brow.

Comment: ahh, the regasm technique, i've heard of this before watching on old VCR tape I found in the couch, I'll go home and try it out tonight, thanks.